# Dart has a standard way to externalize settings like Java properties?

Tags: dart

I'm looking for the right way to externalize the settings in my server Dart application.

In Java the common way would be a property file. Exists something similar in Dart?

Answer (score 5):

You can just use a Dart script for your settings. No point in using a different format if there is no specific reason. 
With a simple import you have it available in a typed way.

Comment: The point of an external config file is usually so that development and production environments can use different values. This wouldn't work so well with the solution you propose.

Comment: If you don't check it in you have just that. You also wouldn't check in a settings file with service passwords. This is an advantage of a scripting language without a compilation step.

Comment: When you say a "Dart script", are you talking about something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35848325/3681880)?

Comment: @Suragch yes, that's what I mean.

Answer (score 4):

When the `Resource` class is implemented, I would just use a JSON file that is deployed with my program.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a global variables, for example:

```
DB_URL = 'localhost:5432/mydb';
DB_PASS = 'my_pass';
```

then you could create a different configuration file for every enviroment. For example, for production you could create a production_config.dart which could contains:

```
loadConfig() {
  DB_URL = '123.123.123.123:5432/mydb';
  DB_PASS = 'my_prod_pass';
}
```

Then in your main function you could call `production_config.loadConfig` if environment is production, for example:

```
import 'production_config.dart' as prodConfig;

main(List<String> args) {
  var ENV = getEnvFromArgs(args);
  if(ENV == 'PROD') {
    prodConfig.loadConfig();
  }
  //do other stuff here
}
```

In that way if you want to change from development to production you only need to pass an argument to your dart program for example:

```
dart myprogram.dart -env=PROD
```

The advantages of this approach are that you don't need to create a separate properties, json or yaml file for this, and you don't need to parse them. Furthermore the properties are type-ckecked.

Comment: Yes it's a good solution but again you can't load the config from external file. If you want to make a change in production URL you need to rebuild and redeploy.

Answer (score 2):

I like putting configuration in a Dart class like [what Günter Zöchbauer was talking about](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35848325/3681880), but there is also the option of using the [safe_config](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/safe_config) package. With this you enter the values in a yaml file. Quoting from the docs:

> You define a subclass of Configuration with those properties:
>
> ```
> class ApplicationConfiguration extends Configuration {
>   ApplicationConfiguration(String fileName) : 
>       super.fromFile(File(fileName));
>
>   int port;
>   String serverHeader;
> }
> ```
>
> Your YAML file should contain those two, case-sensitive keys:
>
> ```
> port: 8000
> serverHeader: booyah/1
> ```
>
> To read your configuration file:
>
> ```
> var config = new ApplicationConfiguration("config.yaml");
> print("${config.port}"); // -> 8000
> print("${config.serverHeader}"); // -> "booyah/1"
> ```

See also an [example](http://aqueduct.io/docs/tut/writing-tests/) from a setup in Aqueduct.

Answer (score 0):

```
main() { 
  var env = const String.fromEnvironment("ENV", defaultValue: "local");
  print("Env === " + env);

}
```

Give environment as option while running Dart App
    pub serve --port=9002 --define ENV=dev

## References:

http://blog.sethladd.com/2013/12/compile-time-dead-code-elimination-with.html
https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/27998