# is possible have a configuration file in DART?

Tags: dart, properties-file

I have this JavaScript class:

```
'use strict;'
/* global conf */

var properties = {
    'PROPERTIES': {
        'CHANNEL': 'sport',
        'VIEW_ELEMENTS': {
            'LOADER_CLASS': '.loader',
            'SPLASH_CLASS': '.splash'
        }
    }
};
```

In JavaScript I can use these properties: `properties.PROPERTIES.CHANNEL`

Is it possible to convert this to DART? Is there a best practise to do that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are different way.

You could just create a map

**my_config.dart**

```
const Map properties = const {
  'CHANNEL': 'sport',
  'VIEW_ELEMENTS': const {
    'LOADER_CLASS': '.loader',
    'SPLASH_CLASS': '.splash'
  }
}
```

then use it like

**main.dart**

```
import 'my_config.dart';

main() {
  print(properties['VIEW_ELEMENTS']['SPLASH_CLASS']);
}
```

or you can use classes to get proper autocompletion and type checking

**my_config.dart**

```
const properties = const Properties('sport', const ViewElements('.loader', '.splash'));

class Properties {
  final String channel;
  final ViewElements viewElements;
  const Properties(this.channel, this.viewElements;
}

class ViewElements {
  final String loaderClass;
  final String splashClass;
  const ViewElements(this.loaderClass, this.splashClass);
}
```

**main.dart**

```
import 'my_config.dart';

main() {
  print(properties.viewElements.splashClass);
}
```

Comment: I would also go for the 2nd but people coming from JS often prefer less classes. Using one of these solutions for browser applications you need to compile the configuration with the application though.

Answer (score 2):

Following up on the above answer using classes, it may be convenient to implement static variables, the downside is that it still must be compiled/rebuilt.

```
class CONFIG {
  static final String BUILD = "Release";
  static final String DEPLOYMENT = "None";
}
```

This can be used from a separate class after importing via:

```
var xyz = CONFIG.BUILD;
```